# Changing Void function to Return Value function

Tags: c++, return, void

Given a currently functioning program using a void function: Change the program so the void function does not output the value of a variable but sends to the main function.

```
void trackVar(double& x, double y);

int main()
{
    double one, two;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Enter two numbers: ";
    cin >> one >> two;
    cout << endl;

    trackVar(one, two);
    cout << "one = " << one << ", two = " << two << endl;

    trackVar(two, one);
    cout << "one = " << one << ", two = " << two << endl;

    return 0;
}
void trackVar(double& x, double y)
{
    double z;
    z = floor(x) + ceil(y);
    x = x + z;
    y = y - z;

    cout << "z = " << z << ", ";
}
```

I can get so the output lists the values for one and two correctly, but do not know how to have output for 'z' as part of the main function.

Final result (for those interested):

```
double trackVar(double& x, double y); ///function prototype (switched to double instead of void)

int main()
{
    double one, two, z;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Enter two numbers: ";
    cin >> one >> two;
    cout << endl;

z = trackVar(one,two);
    cout <<"z= "<<z<<" "<<"one= "<<
    one<<"two= "<<two<< endl;
z = trackVar(two,one);
    cout <<"z= "<<z<<" "<<"one= "<<
    one<<"two= "<<two<< endl;

    return 0;
}

double trackVar(double& x, double y)
{
    double z;
    z = floor(x) + ceil(y);
    x = x + z;
    y = y - z;

    return z;
}
```

Comment: Start with changing `void trackVar(double& x, double y);` to `double trackVar(double& x, double y);` and return `z` from the function instead of printing it.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you have `double& x` but only `double y`.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question

Comment: It's labeled as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking, I update my post.

try this:

```
void trackVar(double& x, double& y)
{
    double z;
    z = floor(x) + ceil(y);
    x = x + z;
    y = y - z;
}
```

So, the normal function`trackVar(double x, double y)`  it will sent a copy x and y into the function, so even you chang them in there, nothing changes.
   But, if you using reference,`trackVar(double& x, double& y)`, to change x and y there, it will really change the value, so be careful using reference.

for a simple example:

```
void trackVar(double& a, double& b)
{
     a = 99;
     b = 66;
}

int main()
{
    double a = 1;
    double b = 2;

    trackVar(a, b);
    std::cout << "New a: "<< a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "New b: " << b << std::endl;
    return 0;  
}
```

output: `New a: 99`
output: `New b: 66`

Comment: I have set the function to 'double' instead of 'void' and 'return z;' at the end of the trackVar function.  All of the output is still correct, however it is not listing the correct 'z' values. Below is an example of my output, all is correct except Z values should be "8.00" and "16.00", accordingly.

Comment: Enter two numbers: 3 5

z= 0.00 one = 11.00, two = 5.00
z= 0.00 one = 11.00, two = 21.00

Comment: My fault, I forgot to remove `&` in your code, if it still weird,
you have to share us how both  `floor`and `ceil` works.

Comment: How they work conceptually? Or in reference to this program? Floor returns highest integer less that a decimal and ceiling is lowest integer greater than a decimal number.  The '&'s were part of the given program, originally.

Comment: Well, I recommend edit your post and add these two functions code ,and tell us what you'll get after changes .

Comment: OH wait, are you trying to do  `trackVar` function to influence the x and y values?

Comment: Yes.  I do not believe the syntax surrounding them should change, its only implementing Z in the main function via a return function instead of using an output at the end of a void function.

Comment: ***I do not believe the syntax surrounding them should change, its only implementing Z in the main function via a return function instead of using an output at the end of a void function.*** If the signature can not change, you could do a `x=z` at the end of the function then use the first parameter to return the value of `z` instead of the value of `x`. It does not return the value of `y` since you pass `y` by value. There is no point of the `y` calculation. Also in this case there is no point of the `x = x + z;` so you can delete that line and `y = y - z;` if you want.

Comment: I finally got it.  I will update the original post with the final result.  Thank you for your time and help.  Its difficult to relay the syntax needed when I have the original program, desired change, and an end result and all the functions are pretty meaningless!